# I'm getting "Error:expected ';' after class definition" after using class in c++

Tags: c++

I seriously have no idea what has gone wrong here. It would be nice if somebody could help.By the way I'm using Codeblocks. I was just trying to write a program using class but something seems out of place. Any help would be appreciated.If u have any doubts just ask me in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int m = 50;

class ITEMS
{
    int itemcode[m];
    float itemprice[m];
    int count;
public:
    void CNT(void) { count = 0 };
    void getitem(void);
    void displaysum(void);
    void remove(void);
    void displayitems(void);
};

{
    cout << "Enter item code:";
    cin >> itemcode[count];
    cout << "Enter item cost:";
    cin >> itemprice[count];
    count++;
}

void ITEMS::displaysum(void)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i < count; i++)
        sum = sum + itemprice[i];
    cout << "\nTotal value:" << sum << "\n";
}

void ITEMS::remove(void)
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter item code:";
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (itemcode[i] == a)
            itemprice[i] = 0;
}

void ITEMS::displayitems(void)
{
    cout << "\nCode Price\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
        cout << "\n" << itemcode[i];
        cout << " " << itemprice[i];
        }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    ITEMS order;
    order.CNT();
    int x;
    do
        {
        cout << "\nYou can do the following";
        cout << "Enter appropriate number \n";
        cout << "\n1: Add an item";
        cout << "\n2: Display total value";
        cout << "\n3: Delete an item";
        cout << "\n4: Display all items";
        cout << "\n5: Quit";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x)
            {
            case 1:  order.getitem(); break;
            case 2: order.displaysum(); break;
            case 3: order.remove(); break;
            case 4: order.displayitems(); break;
            case 5: break;
            default: cout << "Error in input; try again\n";
            }
        }
    while (x != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Error shown in compiler:

```
Error:||=== Build: Debug in C++ (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\C++\Member.cpp|15|error: expected ';' after class definition|
E:\C++\Member.cpp|16|error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token|
E:\C++\Member.cpp||In member function 'void ITEMS::displaysum()':|
E:\C++\Member.cpp|27|error: expected ';' before '<' token|
E:\C++\Member.cpp|27|error: expected primary-expression before '<' token|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

My desired output is:

```
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an Item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an Item
 4:Display all items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?1
 Enter item code :111
 Enter item cost :100
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an Item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an Item
 4:Display all Items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?!
 Enter Item code :222
 Enter Item cost :2DO
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an item
 4:Display all items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?1
 Enter item code :333
 Enter item cost :300
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an Item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an Item 
 4:Display all Items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?2
 Total value :600
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an Item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an item
 4:Display all items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?3
 Enter Item code :222
 You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
 1:Add an item
 2:Display total value
 3:Delete an item
 4:Display all items
 5:Quit
 What is your option?4
 Code Price
  111 100
  222 0
  333 300
You can do the following; Enter appropriate number
1:Add an item
2:Display total value
3:Delete an item
4:Display all items
5:Quit
What is your option?5
```

Comment: That blob of code starting at `{
cout<<"Enter item code:";` (right after the class definition) is at the wrong place. Did you mean to have a line `void ITEMS::getitem(void)` before that? It looks like a function body for `getitem`, but currently it's just a syntax error.

Comment: You have `class ITEMS { ... }; { ... }`... What is that extra `{ ... }` doing after the `ITEM` class definition?

Comment: @MaxLanghof where should it be placed then? :0

Comment: @TechGeek If you want that chunk of code to be the function body for `getitem`, you need to add the line `void ITEMS::getitem(void)` before it.

Comment: There are more syntax errors in here: `for (int i < count; i++)` is not a proper `for` loop and `void CNT(void){count = 0};` is missing a semicolon after the `0`. See https://godbolt.org/z/XxP8kr.
Also, you should put more effort into the indentation of your code. Right now it's a complete mess. See the online compiler code above for one way how the code could be indented properly.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Man! You made my day! Thanks!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess your asking about :: it is the scope resolution operator.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yeah i corrected it but forgot to edit it here. But thanks!